# problem with user registration script in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Im novice on developing with node, and i´m trying to make a simple registration/login script without using any db at the moment, but i´m pushing the data inside an array.

The problem is, when i´m running this script, it´s going to ignore what in the *try* is, jumping directly on the *catch*...

How can i fix it? Thanks!!

////////////////////////////

Problem solved! Tanks!

```
const users = [];

app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{

   try{
      const hashedPsw = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
      users.push({
         id: Date.now().toString(),
         name: req.body.name,
         email: req.body.email,
         psw: hashedPsw
      })
      res.redirect('/login')
   } catch {
      res.redirect('/register')
   }
   console.log(users);
})
```

Comment: You should catch an actual object and log it in the catch handler, so you can see what caused the error. Could be a missing field in req.body or a bcrypt error or something else.  In general don’t use exceptions for normal flow control if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit your catch to

```
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.redirect('/register');
}
```

this way you can see what error is happening and try to fix it later :)